# International wire transfer confusion between the US and Japan

Tags: international-transfer, japan, swift

The recipient Tokyo bank is Mitsubishi UFJ Bank (SWIFT Code MTBCJBJT). This bank after mergers may now be the MUFG Bank (SWIFT Code BOTKJPJT).

First confusion is which SWIFT Code to use?  XXX at the end or nothing indicates the head office.

Add a 3-number code, in this case 360 and that should be the Branch Code.

But when I enter the Account Code, do I use the Branch Code again or is that redundant?

NOTE: I made one attempt previously with a US bank agent on the phone, but the US dollar equivalent of the Japanese yen funds eventually was returned.  I want to get this right.

Comment: Did you try to ask the target bank what SWIFT code they use?

Comment: Almost NO CUSTOMER would know their Bank's SWIFT code. I have a language barrier here, but will try sending both SWIFT Codes to the recipient and see if she can find out which one is correct. Thank you.